# Karate - XML Assertion with regex for a number

Tags: karate

For the following data,

```
<Document xmlns="http://www.mycompany.net/xyz/2.2">
    <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name="Value">
                <value>6.5</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name="Direction">
                <value>77</value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>0,-25.2</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name="Value">
                <value>7.0</value>
            </Data>
            <Data name="Direction">
                <value>101</value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>3.6,-25.2</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
```

I am trying to validate the coordinates that have numbers in the XML. I tried to use Regex but still it fails

```
    When def xmld = read('classpath:rough/GriddedElementResponse.xml')
    * match $xmld/Document/Placemark[*]/Point/coordinates == "#[] #string" 
    # Above gets passed as the numbers are inside quotes
    * match $xmld/Document/Placemark[*]/Point/coordinates == "#regex [\\d \\. \\, \\-]"
```

Fails with the following error in Karate but passes [here](https://regexr.com/).

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not a string (LIST:STRING)
  ["0,-25.2","3.6,-25.2"]
  '#regex [\d \. \, \-]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of 2 strings, please pay attention to the error message.

Try this:

```
* match each $xmld/Document/Placemark[*]/Point/coordinates == '#regex \\d+(\\.\\d+)?,-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)'
```

Comment: Ahh, I miss the `each` keyword, thank you @peter

Comment: Had more dynamic values in coordinates and tweaked a little bit `#regex (\\d+\\.?\\d*),-?\\d+(\\.?\\d?)` and it worked.